# Redundancy with no consultation

Tags: united-kingdom, employment

I was recently made redundant after working at the company for just over a year.

I was given no indication before hand that I personally might be made redundant (although other departments in the company had just gone through redundancies, but this was over a month before) and did not go through a consultation period, I was called into a room with HR and my manager and basically told I was being made redundant and that while given a months notice I was not expected to work it and made to leave the building.

My question is that it was my understanding that the process of redundancy was the employees had to be notified about the potential redundancy or at least have a consultation period so they can ask questions or raise any objections?

This was in the UK.

Comment: Specify how you reached that understanding (for instance, if it is based on a contract or HR/employees' manual), as that might be relevant. Also, be sure to state what exactly you are asking. Whether employment was in IT is irrelevant to whether any legal remedies are available.

Comment: Sorry, I only added that as extra information in case it made any difference as I have very little legal knowledge.

Comment: In the U.S. this would be perfectly legal. The U.K. law is more pro-employer so I'll defer to others.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [requirement of consultation](https://www.gov.uk/redundant-your-rights/consultation), and if they don't follow the rules you can make a [claim to an employment tribunal](https://www.gov.uk/employment-tribunals). Then urge following internal grievance procedures, and before you make a claim you need to tell the Advisory, Conciliation and Arbitration Service that you plan to do so. However, if 20 or more employees are made redundant at once, then the consultation can be with a representative employee (either union or elected).